# backbone model doesn't match expected structure

Tags: backbone.js, titanium

When running this code in my titanium app:

```
var events = Alloy.createCollection('Events');
events.fetch({ async : false });

var firstEvent = events.first();
var eventId = firstEvent.eventId;

Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(firstEvent));
Ti.API.info(eventId);
```

I get this output:

```
[INFO] {"eventId":"62243","eventDate":"2014-10-27T12:46:09.364-04:00","eventName":"Atlanta, GA","street1":"street address","city":"Atlanta","state":"GA","zip":"30303"}
[INFO] <null>
```

Why is the eventId variable null? How do I get the eventId, or any of the other object properties, properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
events.first()
```

returns a backbone model

you can do

```
events.first().get("eventId")
```

to get the eventId

that's how we get model properties properly

Comment: Thanks, obviously I'm new to backbone.js